# type does not take parameters in generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface that takes a generic argument:

```
package com.lbv.itf;

public interface Segment<T extends Object> {...}
```

and this was written couple of years back, compiled in 1.6 and built into a jar, say segment.jar

Now, I have a new project using segment.jar and in this new project, I have a class implementing this interface:

```
package com.lbv.impl; 

import com.lbv.itf.Segment;

public class TreeSegment implements Segment<Tree> {...}
```

compiling this newer class in 1.7 gives this error:

> type com.lbv.itf.Segment does not take parameters

It looks so obvious that Segment interface takes the parameter but somehow, that is not visible while compiling the newer class. Is this a known JDK compatibility issue or is there something I am missing? Any help will be of great help.

**UPDATE:**
It works only if I compile the newer code 1.6 :(. Is there a compatibility issue from 1.6 to 1.7 on generics type parameters?

I am using

> Java 1.6 Update 45 64 bit

and

> Java 1.7 Update 60 64 bit

Comment: I would double check the imports

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the correct `Segment`?  There is a [`javax.swing.text.Segment` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Segment.html) that isn't generic.

Comment: Error is exactly about the Segement interface I am referring to. I have added the package and import statements to make it clear, also the error.

Comment: You are missing code between `public` and `TreeSegment` (ie `class` or `interface`). It matters.

Comment: @Bohemian that was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happend because the legacy code was compiled with the option `

> 'target=jsr14'

` which stripped off the type parameters so that generated code will stay compatible with older java versions. Unfortunately, 1.7 has stopped supporting this flag resulting in the issue that caught me.